# What's the cleanest way to set \emergencystretch only for one list item?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, indentation, enumitem, grouping

Feeding `pdflatex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[USenglish,latin]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=nohyphenation]{latin}
\usepackage{enumitem}%%% the same problem occurrs with usual LaTeX lists, but I use enumitem anyway in my non-minimal text, so let's have it in our example and suggested solutions, too.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{USenglish}%
  Text before the list.%
\end{otherlanguage}%
%\begingroup\setlength\emergencystretch{.13em}%%% if we do this, an unwanted indent after the list appears.
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
%\begingroup\setlength\emergencystretch{.13em}%%% if we do this, the group logically spans slightly more than it should span, doesn't it?
\item \lipsum[2]%
%\endgroup%%% terminating the group here has no effect.
\item \lipsum[3]%
%\endgroup%%% if we do this, the group logically spans slightly more than it should span, doesn't it?
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}%
%\endgroup%%% if we do this, an unwanted indent after the list appears.
\begin{otherlanguage}{USenglish}%
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
\end{otherlanguage}%
\end{document}
```

leads to an overfull:

[image: output]

To get rid of an overfull “vestibulum” in the second item, I locally set `\emergencystretch` to some possibly small value (ideally, less than the 3em of `\sloppy`) so that the change doesn't affect the rest of the typesetting too much. I am aware of the following solutions in this vein:

1. Wrapping the whole list into `\begingroup\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}` […] `\endgroup`. However, it incurs an indentation right after the list, which was not there before. You can counteract this with `\noindent`, but this would logically be a hack undoing the side effect of a solution for something unrelated. (Perhaps, under circumstances, the preferred page break or the distance between the list and the following text might change, though I don't observe such a change in my example.)
2. Wrapping the second and (a part of?) the third item into `\begingroup\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}` […] `\endgroup`.  However, it logically spans more than it should span; namely, the span includes (a part of?) the third item without its line break. Also, this solution is not available if the list has no items after the overfull one (in our minimal example: if there is no third item).
3. Wrapping the second and (a part of?) the third item into `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}` […] `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{0pt}`.  However, it incurs setting the length TWICE (rather than setting it and then undoing the local change), which might potentially lead to hard-to-catch errors during further text edits.

Is there any cleaner solution? If so, what would it be?

Comment: I'm curious as to what the answer is going to be. What I find myself doing is manually adding a `\linebreak` (with a comment), or manually adding a possibly questionable hyphenation break with `\-` (again with comment).  But now you have to go revisit those (at least the line breaks) if you ever change the margins or font size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{<dimen>}\par}` at the end of the item.

Here I pass the `nopar` option to `lipsum`, so to really emulate a normal paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[USenglish,latin]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=nohyphenation]{latin}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{USenglish}
  Text before the list.
\end{otherlanguage}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}\par}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\begin{otherlanguage}{USenglish}
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
  Text after the list.
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does it work? Because the setting to `\emergencystretch` is local to the group where `\par` is executed. The paragraph is broken with this setting turned on, but after the `}` is sensed, it returns to its previous value (typically 0pt).

*Look, ma! No %!*

Comment: First, thanks! Second, would there be any difference between `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}\par}` and `\begingroup\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}\par\endgroup`?

Comment: @GeekestGeek No difference. By the way, you cannot apply `\emergencystretch` to just a part of a paragraph: all or nothing. But the paragraphing algorithm is quite smart anyway. You should also try using `microtype` before resorting to these tricks.

Comment: Thx! Out of curiosity, how does the `\item` or `\end{itemize}` command after `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}\par}` know that a line break terminating the previous item has already happened and it doesn't have to introduce yet another line break as usual?

Comment: @GeekestGeek I'm not sure what you mean: if you leave blank lines between `\item`s, the output doesn't change. Essentially, two consecutive `\par` commands do nothing more than a single one does.

Comment: What I meant is that after the *text* of an item you have some command (`\item` or `\end{itemize}`) which introduces a line break by itsself. It is interesting that an additional `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}\par}` right after the text of the second item does ***not*** increase the number of line breaks (or, more precisely, the amount of vertical white space). Is the reason that `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}\par}\par` (magically) is equivalent to `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.13em}\par}`? And the reason for this is that (magically) `\par\par` = `\par`?

Comment: @GeekestGeek As I said, `\par\par` is essentially the same as `\par`.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: Can I also put `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{…}\par}` if a block math environment  (say, `\begin{gather*}…`) follows or would it add a vertical space?

Comment: @GeekestGeek That's a different case indeed. But you can do `\begingroup\emergencystretch{...}` before the `gather` and `\endgroup` after it.